# Ajuda com Heurísitica em haskell

Tags: haskell

Boa tarde, pessoal estou com um problema aqui para ser resolvido em haskell, a descrição dele é a seguinte:

"Problema  do  Corte  original  é  o  Problema  do  Corte Unidimensional, que  consiste  em  cortar  uma  única  barra  de  material  em  pedaços menores, seguindo sempre padrões de tamanhos previamente definidos. Objetivo é aproveitar ao máximo o material, ou seja, minimizar a sobra.

Desenvolver em Haskell uma heurística para resolver o Problema do Corte Unidimensional. Como entrada básica para a heurística a ser desenvolvida 
receba os seguintes parâmetros: 
•t: tamanho da barra a ser cortada em pedaços menores; 
•[p1,p2,...,pn]: lista do conjunto de padrões de corte. 
A heurística a ser desenvolvida deve ser baseada na escolha aleatória dos padrões de corte. Ou seja, enquanto a sobra do material for maior do que o menor dos padrões, um novo padrão de corte deve ser selecionado e adicionado a solução do problema. "

Daí para gerar os valores aleatórios será usada a biblioteca Random, e eu estou a alguns dias tentando pensar como fazer isso e não chego a lugar nenhum, não sei por onde começar. Alguem por favor poderia dar uma luz? Obrigado de verdade =)

Comment: Chegou a fazer algum código já? Poste o que você já fez.

Comment: Tentamos fazer algo assim aqui:
import System.Random (randomRIO)

randomSimples x = randomRIO(1,x)

processa list valor = valor <-randomSimples (legth list)

escolhe list valor max = if valor > max 
       then processa list valor
       else valor

seleciona list valor tamanho max= escolhe list valor max, tamanho <- list !! valor, print(tamanho)
   
 
max x lista | (minimum lista) <= x = seleciona list valor tamanho max, max(x-tamanho) lista
 |otherwise = putStrLn "Resto: ",print(x)

Mas ja na primeira linha não vai pra frente.

Comment: Se for acrescentar algo à pergunta, como código, [edite-a](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/70522/edit).